# Inclusion is a homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Given $B\subseteq X$ with both $B$ and $X$ contractible. How would you prove that the inclusion map $i:B \to X$ is a homotopy equivalence?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H_t$ be the homotopy between $Id_B$ and the constant map $f_B(x)=b$ and $G_t$ the homotopy between the identity of $X$ and the constant map $f_X(x)=b$.
Consider $g:X\rightarrow B$ defined by $g(x)=b$.

$g\circ i=f_B$ and $i\circ g=f_X$

Comment: Thank you. Why are you allowed to choose the constant map $f_X$ so that $f_X(x)=b$ instead of it being given "for some constant"?

Comment: Because if the identity is homotopic to a constant, it is homotopic to any constant.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the specific map Tsemo Aristide gave, there is the following theorem:

If $Y$ is contractible, then any two maps $X\to Y$ are homotopic (indeed they are nullhomotopic).

Reference: For example 'Introduction to Algebraic Topology' by Rotman Theorem 1.13

The proof is not difficult.

With that in mind the statement is completly trivial, as $B$ and $X$ are contractible.
Furthermore every continuous map $B\to X$ is a homotopy equivalence.